# JavaScript objects dependency from another objects

Tags: javascript, oop, widget, javascript-objects

Could someone explain or show me how to incorporate two JavaScript objects, maybe I can call them widgets, to work then together.

Lets say I have a big object (**window**) which represents a explorer window and a smaller object (**toolbar**) which represent toolbar with various buttons. Manipulating them alone (add, delete, change properties and etc.) I have no problems. But how do I make them work together?
For example, if I want to remove **toolbar** from **window** in this way 
`window.Toolbar.Remove()`

`Remove()` function is part of `toolbar` object and would remove **toolbar** it self from DOM, but how do I remove it's reference from window object and set it to `null`. Should I destroy this `toolbar` some how?

And if I destroy main parent object `window`, how should I destroy all smaller objects like `toolbar`?

Any pointers highly appreciated.

Comment: "I have no problems. But how do I make them work together?" You will have to be more specific

Comment: "how do I remove it's reference from window object and set it to null. Should I destroy this toolbar some how?" As long as you haven't done something like `window.toolbar = toolbar` or have't referenced `toolbar` somewhere else in your code, the `toolbar` object will be garbage collected automatically. And even if you have done something like `window.toolbar = toolbar` simply doing `window.toolbar = undefined` or `delete window.toolbar` will remove any references to `toolbar` and it will be garbage collected again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible options here:

1) Make the child widget aware of parent.

You can have something like this (pseudo-code):

```
window.addChild(name, WigdetClass) {
   this[name] = new WigdetClass(this);
}

// add toolbar
window.addChild('toolbar', Toolbar);

// Toolbar constructor accepts `parent` as parameter
Toolbar(parent) {
   this.parent = parent; 
}

Toolbar.prototype.Remove() {
   // remove self from the page
   ...
   // set parent reference to null
   parent.toolbar = null;
}
```

2) Or you can move "Remove" to the parent object:

```
Window.prototype.RemoveChild(child) {
   // remove child from the document
   ...
   var propertyName = this.findChildName(child); // 'toolbar'
   this[propertyName] = null;
}
```

Comment: Second option fits me quite fine. Thanks a lot ;)